# iPhone 6s won't connect to app store via WiFi

Tags: wifi, app-store-connect

I recently updated to iOS 13.3.1. I hadn't been on the app store in a while (not even for updates), but now I can't get on there via WiFi (attempted on two entirely unrelated WiFi networks). If I turn off WiFi, I connect immediately. I'm also unable to administer my Apple ID (payment methods, etc.) while on WiFi. All other functionality seems to work properly - I can get to websites, etc.

Any suggestions what to check?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try resetting the Network Settings and see if that resolves the issue. To reset the Network Settings, go to the Settings app → General → Reset and tap on the Reset Network Settings item. See if that resolves the issue. You'd need to re-enter all the Wi-Fi access point passwords thereafter as resetting network settings deletes the access point passwords. It doesn't change any other setting or delete any user data.